# How is the script tag scoped for individual pages in Svelte/Sapper?

Tags: svelte

An instance of an imported library ([ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io)) in the script tag of one page in Sapper, the instance keeps existing when navigating to other pages.

I tried destroying it within `ondestroy`, but I can't reference the variable referencing the instance (created wihtin `oncreate`).

How can I either scope the script tag to individual pages, or destroy the instance when leaving the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways of accessing things in `ondestroy` that were created in `oncreate`. The first is to add them as properties of the component:

```html
<script>
  import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';

  export default {
    oncreate() {
      this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(...);
      this.scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene(...);
    },

    ondestroy() {
      this.controller.destroy();
      this.scene.destroy();
    }
  };
</script>
```

The second is to use the `this.on("destroy", ...)` form:

```html
<script>
  import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';

  export default {
    oncreate() {
      const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(...);
      const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene(...);

      this.on('destroy', () => {
        controller.destroy();
        scene.destroy();
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering all my newbie questions Rich. Much appreciated!